# I cannot write to my disk despite having permissions

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, permissions

My laptop has windows 10 and logs into a domain. When I plug my external drive for backups I cannot write anything, not even create a folder.[image: Create folder]

I am a user of domain and belong to administrator group on my laptop. 
I tried granting all permissions to everyone, authenticated users, SYSTEM...with no luck.

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdIKk.png)

[image]

How can I recoover write access without formatting my disk?

Comment: Try to reset the permissions from Advanced, and set "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object".

Comment: I already did it

Comment: You might try adding your account to the local machine’s Power Users or Administrators group.

Comment: I added me to both, still doesn't work.

Comment: Must be something to do with your account. In a login as local admin, can you write to the disk? And can you re-assign permissions?